# Different training times when tensorflow is installed using Conda vs Pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda, conda

I recently upgraded to a new machine, with Intel i5-12400. Just to perform a benchmark, I ran the digit classification model using MNIST dataset for 10 epochs. I have ran the same test benchmark on various platforms :

```
Colab CPU : 19 min

Colab GPU Tesla T4 : 90 secs

Kaggle GPU T4X2 : 104 secs

Kaggle P100 : 77 secs

Mac Air (2017 model, i5) : 24 Min

i5 12400 : 20 minutes.

i5 12400 : 5 minutes (libraries installed using pip instead of Conda)
```

I had created the environment using Conda, and installed all the libraries using conda itself. The training time was much worse than my expectations. it took 20 mins to train the model . With 100% load on all 6 cores/12 threads.

Today, I created a new test env, and installed tensorflow using pip. And somehow, the training time has been reduced to 5 minutes only. CPU load has been reduced to 83% on all 6 cores/12 threads.

I reactivated the old env, and that env is taking 20 mins for the same code to run, on same hardware.

These are the outputs from importing tensorflow

**Conda env :**

> 2023-08-25 01:28:27.188375: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in
> performance-critical operations.
>
> To enable the following instructions: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX_VNNI
> FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate
> compiler flags.

**New env using pip :**

> 2023-08-25 01:03:43.490161: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in
> performance-critical operations.
>
> To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other
> operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

Any idea what's going on, because performance jump is MASSIVE, with less load on CPU?

Comment: The messages you're quoting describe the problem adequately, don't they? (Binaries compiled to make more aggressive use of CPU features are faster, but less compatible, as one would expect; the people building the different sets of binaries made different tradeoffs).

Comment: BTW, while this is guesswork, I wouldn't be surprised if one of the major culprits in terms of there being binaries floating around that are extremely conservative in terms of which extensions they use is Apple's Rosetta; using an Intel-compiled Python interpreter on a M1 Mac, only a small subset of extended CPU instructions are available -- we have _lots_ of people asking about crashes caused by attempts to use unsupported opcodes with Rosetta. I wouldn't be one bit surprised if the maintainer threw their hands up after getting too many crash reports and built something slow but supported.

Comment: (so the binaries you install with conda aren't compiled to use SSE4.x, whereas the ones you install with pip are; of course, whenever you want the truly fastest possible thing, you should build from source yourself instead of installing prebuilt binaries in the first place).

Comment: @Charles-Duffy So in this message : To enable the following instructions: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags,it means that this build supports these instructions sets, or not ?  And how do I know which instructions sets my CPU supports if I want to build it myself ?

Comment: I agree with Charles. Even within Conda there are different strategies depending on channel. Not sure about TensorFlow specifically, but I have the impression Anaconda does slightly more optimized builds, whereas Conda Forge aims more for compatibility, but can be more modular. You'd likely get more feedback and possibly help improve the ecosystem by posting an Issue on the feedstock where your Conda `tensorflow` came from. E.g., https://github.com/conda-forge/tensorflow-feedstock/issues. A reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: It's saying you need to rebuild a version optimized for your current CPU to get use of those extensions, which means they aren't available otherwise. But do follow merv's advice to see if you can find prebuilt binaries for your CPU.

Comment: Ya I went to the tensorflow's documentation and they mention that the pip releases are now being maintained by Intel itself. That explains why I am getting optimized version when installed through pip.